# Tag unique rows?

Tags: postgresql

I have some data from different systems which can be joined only in a certain case because of different granularity between the data sets.

Given three columns:

```
call_date, login_id, customer_id
```

How can I efficiently 'flag' each row which has a unique value across those three values? I didn't want to SELECT DISTINCT because I do not know which of the rows actually matches up with the other. I want to know which records (combination of columns) exist only once in a single date.

For example, if a customer called in 5 times on a single date and ordered a product, I do not know which of those specific call records ties back to the product order (lack of timestamps in the raw data). However, if a customer only called in once on a specific date and had a product order, I know for sure that the order ties back to that call record. (This is just an example - I am doing something similar across about 7 different tables from different source data).

```
timestamp          customer_id  login_name  score   unique
01/24/2017 18:58:11    441987      abc123   .25      TRUE
03/31/2017 15:01:20    783356      abc123    1       FALSE
03/31/2017 16:51:32    783356      abc123    0       FALSE


call_date   customer_id  login_name order   unique
01/24/2017       441987   abc123    0        TRUE
03/31/2017       783356   abc123    1        TRUE
```

In the above example, I would only want to join rows where the 'uniqueness' is True for both tables. So on 1/24, I know that there was no order for the call which had a score of 0.25.

Answer (score 1):

To find whether the row (or some set of columns) is unique within the list of rows, you need to make use of [PostgreSQL window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

```
SELECT *, 
   (count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY b, c, d) = 1) as unique_within_b_c_d_columns 
FROM unnest(ARRAY[
    row(1, 2, 3, 1),
    row(2, 2, 3, 2),
    row(3, 2, 3, 2),
    row(4, 2, 3, 4)
]) as t(a int, b int, c int, d int)
```

Output:

```
| a | b | c | d | unique_within_b_c_d_columns |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | true                        |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | false                       |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | false                       |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 4 | true                        |
```

In `PARTITION` clause you need to specify the list of columns that you want to make comparison on. Note that in the example above `a` column doesn't take part in comparison.